# Haskell not sure how to write "vertical programs"

Tags: haskell

Im learning Haskell and I wrote this code to test some concepts of Haskell.

```
identifyThing :: [arg] -> String
identifyThing arg = "This looks like a " ++
    case arg of
        [] -> "empty list"
        [arg] -> "list"
        arg -> "something else"

main :: IO ()
main = putStrLn (identifyThing [])
    putStrLn (identifyThing [1..10]) 
    putStrLn (identifyThing ()) 
    putStrLn (identifyThing 1)
```

I get an error on the first line of the main declaration: cannot apply 7 arguments to putStrLn. I think this is because I don't know how to tell haskell that I am not wrapping the arguments over to the next line.

I would be grateful if somebody could show me what I've done wrong. Thanks.

Comment: You should move the `"a"` part of the string and write `"an empty list"`, `"a list"` and `"something else"` to get the grammar right :p

Comment: Also, note that your cases `[arg] -> "list"` and then `arg -> "something else"` don't really make sense: it should read something like `[arg] -> "singleton list"`; `arg -> "list with length >1"`. (The _type_ `[a]` has a slightly different meaning from the _value_ `[a]`.)

Comment: Thanks for that! Was unsure whether [x] was valid for many members or just an array with members

Comment: Read a tutorial on haskell which explains the concepts more clearly before jumping into programming, otherwise you might develop bad programming habits which will bite you in the future.

Comment: Yeah I was reading learnyouahaskell, but I must have missed something somewhere :)

Comment: Since in your patterns you're not using what `arg` matches, you can replace `arg` with `_`, i.e. `[_] -> "list"` and `_ -> "something else"`. Using the underscore communicates that you won't be using the matching expression on the right hand side.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A longer answer is that in Haskell you can't lump lines together and expect they work in sequence. When you write `do` it's not a syntax for { } - style block or something, it's a syntax for joining the lines using `>>=` function into a bigger line. So when you write `do` it's just a single line in fact:

```
main = putStrLn (identifyThing []) >>= \_ -> putStrLn (identifyThing [1..10]) >>= \_  -> putStrLn (identifyThing [1])
```

Pattern matching (as in `case` or equivalent definitions using multiple equations) works from top to bottom though.

The whole idea of Haskell is that you can't write vertical programs - you can only write horizontal ones :) And usually you can reformulate your "vertical" program into a shorter "horizontal" one. E.g.

```
main = mapM_ (putStrLn . identifying) [[], [1..10], [1]]
```

is another way to say "horizontally" what you wanted to say "vertically".

For beginners `do`, `<-` and `return` constructs are rather misleading. So you should use `>>=`, `>>`, `\ ->` and `return` and then learn how to shorten that using `<$>`, `<*>`, `.`, `liftM2` and other functions from `Control.Monad` and `Control.Applicative`. Also, in many cases you can redesign your algorithms so "vertical" code is not needed anymore in the first place.

For your example, an easy to understand beginner's code would be:

```
main = putStrLn (identifyThing [1..10]) >> putStrLn (identifyThing ()) >> putStrLn (identifyThing 1)
```

Answer (score 4):

Fixed it, using "do" after main, plus a newline, did the trick.

Here's what I used to make it work (also corrected other parts of the program):

```
identifyThing :: [a] -> String
identifyThing arg = "This looks like " ++
    case arg of
        [] -> "an empty list"
        [x] -> "a list with one element"
        x -> "a list with more than one element"

main :: IO ()
main = do
    putStrLn (identifyThing [])
    putStrLn (identifyThing [1..10]) 
    putStrLn (identifyThing [()])
    putStrLn (identifyThing [1])
```

Comment: `()` is a value that has type `()`. It's not nothing. `[()]` is a list with one element, which is `()`. Your code can't correctly say "something else" because the type signature `[a] -> String` forces the first argument to be a list. Calling the type `[arg]` is acceptable but confuses two things, so I changed that too.